# Doubt in Schutz's definition of Inertial observer

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames, observers

In a first course in General relativity by Schutz, page-3, the following definition is given for Inertial observer:

> An observer is simply a coordinate system for space time, which makes an osbervation simply by recording the location $(x,y,z)$ and time $t$ of any event.
>
> The coordinate system must satisfy the following three properties to be labelled inertial
>
> 1. Distances between spatial point is independent of time.
> 2. Clocks at every point ticking of the time coordinate $t$ are synchronized and all run at the same rate
> 3. Geometry of space at any constant $t$ is Euclidean

What precisely does it mean for Geometry of space to be Euclidean?

Answer (score 0):

> What precisely does it mean for Geometry of space to be Euclidean?

It means that in space (at any given moment in time) Euclid’s axioms of geometry hold. The sum of the interior angles of a triangle is 180 degrees. Parallel lines don’t intersect. Etc.

The easiest way to see if this is correct is to look at the metric. If there exists a coordinate transform such that the metric is $ds^2=-dt^2+ dx^2+dy^2+ dz^2$ then for $dt=0$ you get the Pythagorean theorem which is an indicator that the space is Euclidean

Comment: Hmm but he hasn't increased lorentz metric yet. Would geodesic between two point not be straight line if time we changing?